# Which is better when storing some large texts: strings in XML resource file or a java Strings in a class

Tags: android, xml, string

I have to store some long text, to use in textViews. i've always been using strings in a xml file, but i don't know if a java String for each text could be better, so...

Which is the best way to store them:

1. Create strings in a XML resource file
2. Create a class and store the text in java strings

Thanks!

Comment: There is no best way i think. So do what you like to do. But ... what is a java string? String?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XML resource file would be better option.
Keep the class file code as clean as possible.

Comment: Thanks! Clear and fast answer!

Comment: There is no reasoning provided. Why is it okay to have mess in xml resource compare to class code? What if it is a very simple class?

Comment: @rpattabi, one reason I use the XML files rather than Java classes is easy locale management.  Example: [https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages)