# Is it okay to use strings.xml Resource file for storing large text in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, storage

I am making an offline encyclopedia app. So large text data must be stored for using them when required. So is it a good practice to use strings.xml resource file to store such large amount of text data? Will it result in any kind of performance issues?

Comment: yes of course you can save...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, of course. it's better to use for your text even large static text.
Check some useful links for better understanding:
[Which is better when storing some large texts: strings in XML resource file or a java Strings in a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367712/which-is-better-when-storing-some-large-texts-strings-in-xml-resource-file-or-a)

[Load Large Text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151152/copy-large-text-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

It is suggested way to use XML resource files which will also ease your job in case you want to [localize](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) your application with string resources.